# How to run a grails app as a service on windows

Tags: windows, grails, service

I know you can and should run grails on tomcat, but I have to run it from the command line "grails run-app" on a server for a period of time.

The problem is, when that user is logged out, the grails process is killed.

Windows doesn't have something like nohup, and I think the only option is to run it as a service.  The question is, how?

I don't have access to the windows resource kit (unless it can be downloaded for free from somewhere), and am very loathed to download any third party apps claiming to run something as a service.

Comment: Have you already looked at this? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192 also what version of windows?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Very interesting, but I cant see how to specify the path where the command is run, only the path of the binary.  grails needs to be in the right app dir to run it.  Its windows Server 2008 Dataceter edition. sc is installed.

Comment: Pehraps instead of a binary you could use a batch file which of course can execute grails in the correct directory. Just a thought. Besides, doing what you are doing is really unusual and I wouldn't ever do it in production. Ever.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar case. The solution I had was to create a bat file with the sequence of commands that I intended. As can be seen in the lines below.
Later create a variable in regedit in:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SOFTWARE \ Microsoft \ Windows \ CurrentVersion \ Run`
which points to the .bat file you created.
But before that you should have the java and grails PATHS properly configured.

```
cd workspace \ mz.maleyanga \\ where is my app  
grails prod runApp
```